# CodeIgniter 4 - Refused to get unsafe header "Debugbar-Time"

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I just installed CodeIgniter 4, configured the .env file to "development" and did also set the base url. For some strange reason, when I load a controller I get this error concernig the CI debug bar:

[image]

How can I solve this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try by removing 3rd party js plugins. In my case Paypals checkout.js is causing the issue when ci4 is in development environment. It will be gone when you switch to production

Answer (score -2):

This Answer maybe too late. But I just want to inform to some poeple that have an issue like this. So in my trouble, I just remove some **js** in my apps. It's work for me.

Comment: "I just remove some js in my apps" - specifically?

Comment: removing the code obviously removes the error... but not seems to me a smart solution